# how to have Web Api send Json.net Serialized string object back to client Correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net, booksleeve

I am serializing an IEnumerbale object using JsonConvert.SerializeObject( );
it produces string with quotes and escape character with spaces

from web Api controller i return that string  using code below

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetDegreeCodes(int id)
{
    string result = //output from JsonConvert.SerializeObject( );
    return result;
}
```

> "[{\"DegreeId\":1,\"DegreeName\":\"High School\",\"ImageSrc\":\"
>   http://bootsnipp.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114-pre\",\"Description\":\"
>   Get High School
>   Degree\r\"},{\"DegreeId\":2,\"DegreeName\":\"Associate\",\"ImageSrc\":\"
>   http://bootsnipp.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114-pre\",\"Description\":\"
>   Get Associate
>   Degree\r\"},{\"DegreeId\":3,\"DegreeName\":\"Bachelor\",\"ImageSrc\":\"
>   http://bootsnipp.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114-pre\",\"Description\":\"
>   Get Bachelor
>   Degree\r\"},{\"DegreeId\":4,\"DegreeName\":\"Masters\",\"ImageSrc\":\"
>   http://bootsnipp.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114-pre\",\"Description\":\"
>   Get Master
>   Degree\r\"},{\"DegreeId\":5,\"DegreeName\":\"Doctrate\",\"ImageSrc\":\"
>   http://bootsnipp.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114-pre\",\"Description\":\"
>   Get Doctorate Degree\"}]"

**This is my ajax and it does not recognize the JSON correctly because of the extra wrapper quotes and escape characters,**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/helloservice/getdegreecodes",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/text",
        data: { id: 1 }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                viewEduModel.degreeCodes.push(data[i]);
            }

        }
    });
```

> i need to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject since i am caching it as a JSon
>   in my redis cache server using booksleeve that way I do not need to
>   re serialize and read from db every time.  how do i avoid web api controller sending
>   Quotes and backslashes? i could simply return IEnumerable and
>   let Web Api do the JSOn serialization but i need to cache it on redis
>   side

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could something like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetDegreeCodes(int id)
{
    StringContent sc = new StringContent("Your JSON content from Redis here");
    sc.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
    resp.Content = sc;

    return resp;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, just don't serialise the results yourself.

Comment: Did you read the last para of the OP. The user wants to store the content in Redis as Json and so he doesn't want to re-serialize the conent.

Answer (score 0):

by using this you can call your webapi through code.

```js
using (var client = new WebClient()) //WebClient  
{
   string mystring = "";               
  client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json"); //Content-Type  
  client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");                      
  var dataa = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"Username\":\"sdfsd\"}");                      
  byte[] a = client.UploadData("your API url", "POST",dataa);                        
  myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a);
  
  }
```